# How to remove a single relationship?

Tags: suitecrm

I have created a custom module and added some relationships with the other modules. I wanted to remove a single relationship from the list of relationships. is any option to remove a single relationship instead of 'Clear Relationships' under reset module?

Answer (score 1):

If you have created your relationship through Studio you should be able to delete it from there, so:

```
 *- Admin -> Studio -> ~your_module~ -> Relations -> ~your_relation~ -> Delete*
```

In case you are not allowed you can use another method. You should first delete two files:

- Metadata file:
  *custom\metadata\~relationship_name~MetaData.php*
- TableDictionary file: 
  *custom\Extension\application\Ext\TableDictionary\~relationship_name~.php*

Now you have to remove fields from both related modules:

- *custom\Extension\modules\~first_module_name~\ext\vardef\~field_name~.php*
- *custom\Extension\modules\~second_module_name~\ext\vardef\~field_name~.php*

P.S: Remember to backup before deleting any files